# Changed property not saved with Magical Record

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I am using Magical Record to manage my core data stack. Throughout my app I have been using the saveWithBlock method to save and it all works fine.
However in one specific save, the changes are not being saved. I am trying to add a new group to an existing photo object.

I tried printing the photos.groups.count before the save and after in the completion block, the count does increment. But when I run this code again with the same photos, the photos.groups.count goes back to 1, which means no new groups were added.

```
//check if this asset has been processed before
    __block PTPhoto *photo = [PTPhoto fetchWithAsset:asset];
    if (photo && ![[photo groups] containsObject:group]) {
        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            PTGroup *localGroup = [group MR_inContext:localContext];
            photo = [photo MR_inContext:localContext];
            [photo addGroup:localGroup];
            [photo addGroupsObject:localGroup];
        } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            [[PTNetwork defaultNetwork] updatePhoto:photo WithAddedGroup:group WithCompletion:^{
                dispatch_group_leave(ProcessImageGroup());
            }];
        }];
    }
```

I wrote my own addGroup method to add item to the NSSet

```
-(void)addGroup:(PTGroup *)group {
    NSMutableSet *mutableGroups = [self mutableSetValueForKey:@"groups"];
    [mutableGroups addObject:group];
}
```

I have also tried using the core data generated method with no luck

```
@interface PTPhoto (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addGroupsObject:(PTGroup *)value;
```

This is how I get the existing photo:

```
+ (PTPhoto *)fetchWithAsset:(PHAsset *)asset {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *assetPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localID == %@", [asset localIdentifier]];
    [request setPredicate:assetPredicate];
    [request setEntity:[PTPhoto entityWithContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]]];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if ([array count]) {
        return array[0];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The PTPhoto and PTGroup is in 1 to Many relationship.

instead of using

```
[photo addGroup:localGroup];
[photo addGroupsObject:localGroup];
```

try the following lines

```
[localGroup setPhoto:photo];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post this as a comment but it got a bit too long.

I'm not sure I'd trust the implementation of MR_inContext to be thread safe. As far as I can see, accessing the `objectID` of photo from a different context seems to violate Coredata's thread confinement. What happens if you try the following:

```
PTPhoto *photo = [PTPhoto fetchWithAsset:asset];
NSManagedObjectID *photoID = [photo objectID];
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
  Photo *localPhoto = [localContext objectWithID:photoID];
  // add photo to group
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
  // You can also try refreshing your photo object on completion to make sure it is not stale
  [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] refreshObject:photo mergeChanges:YES];
  // Do your other network stuff 
}];
```